# How to build secure access for cloud machine in small startup

Tags: vpn, tunnel, gateway, gcp

We have 7 member team (3 dev + 2 qa + 2 Sales).
We host our PROD + QA + DEMO server in `GCP`.

As of now, all our PROD/QA/DEMO/DEV/QA-DB/DEV-DB machine are having public IP, so that we can `ssh` into them.
There are many open ports, so that we can connect to them via public ip and do all our stuff.

We know public ip and open ports are bad and big company create virtual private network. And all cloud machine and developer machine are part of the this network and no public ip and port are required.

So we wanted to do the same, but
1.We dont have a common office.
2.We dont have money to spend on harware.
3.We dont have expertise in networking and creating vpn.

So we started looking at cloud based solution

1. CISCO -- cant find any thing
   and after searching a lot lastly we landed on `perimeter 81` which provide a hosted gateway and a vpn client.
   Then we created a tunnel between our gcp vpn and `perimeter 81` gateway and our usecase seems to be fullfilled.

**NOW,**

How do other very small companies doing it?
Is small companies living on public IP to every machine in cloud?
What are the other options ?

Answer (score 2):

YOU DESPERATELY NEED A FIREWALL!

Sorry for shouting, but *all our PROD/QA/DEMO/DEV/QA-DB/DEV-DB machine are having public IP, so that we can ssh into them. There are many open ports, so that we can connect to them via public ip and do all our stuff* makes my skin crawl.

Being a small startup is no excuse - the Internet is generally hostile and anything that is not sufficiently protected WILL be hacked - today, tomorrow, or maybe only next week if you're lucky. There's a fair chance you've already been hacked and haven't noticed it yet.

Using a firewall, you make sure that

1. only services required to be public are visible to the public Internet
2. services you require internally are only visible from specific public IP addresses AND all data/authentication is seriously encrypted
3. alternatively and preferably to 2., you use VPN connections to secure all inbound, internal traffic - once you've set up VPN you can transparently use internal services from remote without having to worry about security and encryption

Once you've set up a firewall you'll also be able to see the amount of hacking that goes on. It can be quite intimidating for a newbie.

You don't necessarily require hardware. If you can configure the network that way you could use one cloud machine to protect the others - there are quite a few decent software firewalls and VPN solutions around, even free/open source. However, product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

If you don't know how to set up a firewall get professional help - this isn't something you can do half way. While we can assist you with specific issues here, we can't design your entire security for you.

Comment: Sir we dont have static IPs all developer work from home usng home internet, so in firewall i cant just add "allow from ip".

Comment: Then you require VPN.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get it done by  deploying  any statefull firewall example Cisco ASA, firepower , fortigate , paloalto , juniper , checkpoint sonic wall are firewalls in market used for configure IPsec VPN Site -Site need to build between Google cloud  and your site and this is more secure connectivity confidentiality , integrity , authentication is provided for your data .

Integrity is provided with hash algorithm
Confidential is provided with various encryption methods
DES(digital encryption standards)
3(DES) digital encryption standard
AES (advances encryption standard)

Authentication is provided by " preshared key"

All above perimeter should match at both Google cloud and our site vpn tunnel creation configuration

With this vpn tunnel your office site users can access resources hosted on Google cloud with private ips , and this traffic is highly secure ..

Comment: Sir just reiterating.
1.We dont have a common office.
2.We dont have money to spend on harware.

Comment: Yes I can understand , but I want to let you know the optimised  way of connectivity to access resources on Google cloud securely

Comment: There are open source VPN options. You can also use one machine with a public IP as a jump box. Every other machine should not have public IPs